# How to input a std::string_view in C++?

Tags: c++, string, c++17, c++20, string-view

This is the normal way to input(kinda) a ***std::string_view*** variable :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str; // Still have to use std::string class // Resulting in stack/heap allocation
    getline(cin, str);

    string_view view(str);

    return 0;
}
```

I was wondering is there any way at all to directly input a ***std::string_view*** without having to use the string class (using heap allocation) ???

[ I definitely know that a ***string literal ( like "Hello")*** is stored directly in the binary code at compile time without causing any stack/heap allocation ... so maybe any way to directly input the string literal into the string_view ??? ]

> Note : I want a user input NOT a hard coded string in the code !

Comment: Nope. You cannot allow a program to store an arbitrary amount of input data without some additional allocation, and `std::string_view` does not allocate any additional data by design. Your code is correctly written.

Comment: `string_view` doesn't have its own storage - it's a view onto storage provided by some other object. But the user input needs to be stored *somewhere*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no way to read input into a string view.

If you want to input a string, you have to store it somewhere. It doesn't necessarily have to be `std::string`, but that is the simplest option.